# Generating a non-IAP receipt in sandbox

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit, receipt-validation

I'm trying to generate a receipt for validation for an app's *purchase*. This is *not* an in-app purchase receipt, rather a receipt that reflects the download itself.
My assumptions is that `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` generates this receipt when running from Xcode.
But it seems using sandbox credentials fails to generate the receipt.

Am I right about my assumption? if I am, how do I generate such as receipt in sandbox environment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bundle identifier matches one that is defined on iTunes Connect (along with other in-app purchases).